# Insert into db and call AJAX for that data in one click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, insert

I've spent several days trying to find an answer for this problem. Although i've read numerous answers to similar questions, i'm having a hard time getting it to work in the context of my problem. I'm new to ajax so i'm hopefully missing a simple step here.

I'm trying to insert data into a table (php/MySQLi) and using ajax to retrieve that data in one click and displaying it on the page. Inserting and ajax both work fine, but the ajax call is always once step behind.

This is the php script for inserting a name + id:

```
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = get_post($con, 'name');
    $query = "INSERT INTO testtable VALUES" . "('$name', 'NULL')";
    $result = $con->query($query);
}

function get_post($con, $var) {
    return $con->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

So far so good, the data is inserted correctly. I'm outputting the data from the table in this script, which is response.php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM testtable";
$result = $con->query($query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    echo <<<_END
    <p>Name:  $fetch[0]</p>
    <p>ID: $fetch[1]</p>
_END;
}
```

This is the ajax script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "response.php", 
            success: function(result) {
            $("#output").html(result);
        }})
    });
});
```

If it helps, here's the html:

```
    <iframe name="frame" style="display: none"></iframe>
<form action="index.php" method="post" target="frame">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" id="button" value="click" name="button">
</form>
<div id="output">Some output here</div>
```

I'm using an iframe as target to prevent the page from refreshing. I've found there are other ways to prevent the page from reloading but this seems to be working good.

Now, whenever I click the submit button, the data is inserted into the db, but there's no ajax output because I guess there's no data available because both the insert and the ajax call are fired at once. On the second submit, the first submit is shown etc. In this construction, Ajax is always lagging one step behind.

Whenever I click to insert I want to immediately output that new entry on the page. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using an iframe as target to prevent the page from refreshing.

Let's not do that.

> Inserting and ajax both work fine, but the ajax call is always once step behind.

I'm not sure how your code is working with AJAX since you never pass the data...

**Solution**

First, let's fix/minimize your HTML. We'll add an ID to your form to reference it after.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
<div id="output">Some output here</div>
```

Next, let's attach an `onsubmit` event handler to your form using jQuery.

```
$('#myform').submit(function (e) {
    var form = $(this);
    // proper way to prevent the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
    // send request WHILE passing the form's data
    // we'll use $.post(url, data, callback) which is a shorthand method to $.ajax()
    $.post('response.php', form.serialize(), function (res) {
         $("#output").html(result);
    });
});
```

Lastly, your two scripts need to be one in `response.php` if they are not... insert logic followed by retrieving logic.

For more information,

- [Shorthand methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/)
- [.serialize() method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
- [.submit() method](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) Read in particular their first example.

Comment: That's excellent! It works great now. I'm not sure how the onsubmit event handler works exactly, so I shall read the suggested documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, they are NOT "fired at once". That is just impossible by its nature - other then by total accident.

Although, right, it MAY happen that the INSERT transaction is not yet over as the DB engine receives SELECT request - for whatever reason.

So as the most usual suspect - check your [autocommit mysqli property](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php) to be ON.

Or, alternatively, do a [commit explicitly](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) after INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Solution1->The simple solution is when you insert data using ajax file and while getting the response from the ajax. Send the data which you want to print in response and set them in a html as success : function(res){ jQuery('.all_data').html(res); }
This will be the more easy solution.
Solution2-> make another ajax call on success of insert complete ajax and fetch the data from table and set them in success